# How do I "stock groceries" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, hispanoamérica

I'm looking for a Spanish word for the English *stocker* and *to stock*, in the sense of putting grocery items on a shelf so that they can be sold.  That is:

> Yo soy un *[sustantivo]* de abarrotes.  Cada noche yo *[verbo]* los abarrotes en el supermercado.  O sea, coloco en los estantes, con mucho cuidado, los productos que vienen en el camión.

The options I've found don't seem suitable:

- colocar

  - This seems to have a much broader usage
- [abastecer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=03damMg)

  - This works for a different sense of the verb "to stock": *that grocery store stocks organic milk*, i.e., it supplies or provides organic milk to its customers.  That's not the sense I'm looking for.
- surtir

  - Also a sense of *providing something to someone*, not putting on a shelf.
- surtirse de

  - Apparently a translation for "to stock up," that is, to buy a lot, but again not the sense of "to stock" that I am looking for.

I'm particularly interested in a word that would be suitable for use in Mexico.

Comment: I'm backing up DarkAjax with his answer of: **Abastecedor/Surtidor** In case of Mexican Spanish "reponedor" is too awkward and fairly not used. This is in the case of Mexico. Source: Raised in the North of Mexico (Baja California and Sonora), lived there for 26 years

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a mexican perspective, I'd think of the word **surtir**, followed by **abastecer** are the ones that sound more natural to me:

> Yo soy un **surtidor** de abarrotes. Cada noche yo **surto** los abarrotes en el supermercado. O sea, coloco en los estantes, con mucho cuidado, los productos que vienen en el camión.
>
> Yo soy un **abastecedor** de abarrotes. Cada noche yo **abastezco** los abarrotes en el supermercado. O sea, coloco en los estantes, con mucho cuidado, los productos que vienen en el camión.

Comment: Gracias!  I think *surtir* is going to be best, based on [these job listings for Soriana](http://www.opcionempleo.com.mx/buscar/empleos?s=surtidor+soriana&l=M%C3%A9xico).

Answer (score 11):

The word you're looking for is *reponedor*.
Hence, your sentence becomes:

> Yo soy un ***reponedor*** de abarrotes. Cada noche yo ***repongo*** los abarrotes en el supermercado. O sea, coloco en los estantes, con mucho cuidado, los productos que vienen en el camión.

---

I just realised you wanted an expression suitable for Mexico. If my answer doesn't fulfil what's expected, I'll delete it.

Comment: I'm not mexican but a short google search finds several job offers for "reponedor con experiencia en grandes superficies" in mexican locations and mexican companies, so I guess this answer applies to Mexico.

Comment: +1.  This is definitely a helpful answer, but from what I can tell *surtir* may be more prevalent in Mexico.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In Argentina.

- "Repositor":

  > Yo soy un **repositor** de góndola. Cada noche yo **repongo** las góndolas en el supermercado. O sea, coloco en los estantes, con mucho cuidado, los productos que vienen en el camión.
- "Repositor": stocker.
- "Góndola": estante.

We call "depósito" the stocking place where products are stocked in boxes not to be seen by clients. 
And of course, sometimes we use Spanglish:

> Yo soy un **stockeador** de depósito. Cada noche **stockeo** la mercadería que viene en el camión.

We use "stockear" to counting products.

Comment: +1 ... but "puaj" for _stokear_ :). Anyway the supermarket industry use "repositor" in Argentina. But you can't say "yo repongo la góndola". Te correct noun is "Yo repongo la mercadería  (que se ha vendido)"

Comment: And "góndola" is "estantería" (not "estante") :D

Comment: Mmm, an "estantería" is made of "estantes". But you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Stockeo, stockear o stockeador, is a "spanglish" word and therefore, incorrect.

The correct translation would be "abastecer".

To stock shelves = "abastecer los anaqueles".

I stock shelves = "yo abastezco los anaqueles".

Answer (score 1):

For Castillian Spanish, the correct translation would be:

> Soy un **reponedor**. Cada noche **repongo** las estanterías en el
>   supermercado. O sea, coloco en los estantes, con mucho cuidado, los
>   productos que vienen en el camión.

NOTE: we don't use "abarrotes" nor "gondolas" to refer to *shelves* (estantes, estanterías)